# Swapping Nodes in pairs

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to solve the following leetcode problem :

Given a linked list, swap every two adjacent nodes and return its head. You must solve the problem without modifying the values in the list's nodes (i.e., only nodes themselves may be changed.)

For example: Input: head = [1,2,3,4]
Output: [2,1,4,3]

I am a newbie to linked lists and have written following code for the above problem:

```
public void swapPairs() {
        if(head == null || head.next == null) {
            return;
        }

        Node prev = head;
        Node firstNode = head;
        Node secondNode = head.next;

        while(secondNode != null) {
            Node nxt = secondNode.next;

            prev.next = secondNode;
            firstNode.next = nxt;
            secondNode.next= firstNode;

            if(nxt == null) {
                break;
            }

            prev = firstNode;
            firstNode = nxt;
            secondNode = firstNode.next;
        }

    }
```

The output above code returning is [1, 4, 3]. I am unable to understand why 2 is not there in the list at the beginning.

Comment: Link to the problem at LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will perform the pairwise swaps correctly, but the `head` reference is never updated, yet it is clear that after this pairwise swapping the head should now be what was the second node in the original ordering.

So add this line, just before the loop:

```
    head = head.next;
```

A visualisation may help. Let's take the example of input list 1,2,3,4:

```
head
  ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: null│
│           │   │           │   │           │   │           │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

Once the `next` references have been updated with your code, we get this:

```
head
  ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ┐   │   │ next: ┐   │   │ next: null│   │ next: ┐   │
│       │   │◄──────────┘   │   │           │◄──────────┘   │
└───────│───┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘ ┌►└───────────┘
        └─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The nodes have been rewired as expected. If we start at the second node and follow the arrows (the `next` references), we see the nodes are chained in the desired order. But, because `head` still references the node with value 1, we will not see the node with value 2 anymore, as it is now ordered *before* that node.

Before the rewiring process starts we should therefore make the `head` reference the node with value 2.

Comment: It worked . Now it is giving correct output but I can not understand how  adding ```head.next``` made 2 appear in the beginning. Can you please elaborate it? :)

Comment: Elaborated on it in my answer.